# How to disable brightness intensity switching by power plans and AC/battery modes?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management, backlight

This is a "feature" in Windows 7, but I can't see how it is useful; it just annoys me.

Every power plan and the AC/battery mode has its own setting for brightness intensity. So, if I switch power plans, the intensity changes, same for when I plug the computer in.

I always setup the light intensity according to light conditions, rarely the power plan. If I really want to save battery, I'm intelligent enough to figure out that I should lower it by myself.

So, my question is, is there a way for Windows 7 to leave the backlight setting alone when switching power plans or AC/battery modes?

Answer (score 0):

From the start menu search box type 'Edit power plan' and hit enter.  This will open the currently selected power plan your computer is using and allow you to edit the details.  There is a slider for display brightness for when on battery and for plugged in.

Comment: I know, but that's separate for each power plan. That's exactly what I *don't* want. I would like to have just one brightness setting, across all power plans (so that if I change it on one power plan, it automatically changes on all others..).