# Link "On Battery" and "Plugged in" screen brightness together?

Tags: laptop, windows-10, brightness, powersave, power-options

Suppose I was in a dark room using my laptop plugged in. I set the brightness to a low value like 25% because the room was dark. Then, I unplugged the charger because the laptop is completely charged. I also set the brightness to 25%. Now I turned the light on and the room became bright. I change the brightness to 100% because the screen was not visible in a bright room. After a while, I connect the charger again, and the brightness turns to 25% again. Logically, this makes no sense because I connected the charger and the laptop has more power to spend and still the laptop tries to save power by lowering the brightness.

This happens because Windows simply remembers the last brightness by the two "On Battery" and "Plugged in" states, not adjusting the other when one changes. Is there any way to link the values together? I mean, when I increase the brightness of "Plugged in", I would also want the brightness of "On Battery" to increase, so that I will not have to adjust the screen brightness each time I connect or disconnect the charger.

Ideally, I wish "On Battery" brightness should be set relative to the "Plugged In" brightness, for example, "On Battery brightness is -25% of Plugged In brightness".

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/266684/how-to-disable-brightness-intensity-switching-by-power-plans-and-ac-battery-mode but it doesn't have good answer..

Answer (score 0):

I created my own program doing that behaviour. It changes the other when one changed.

https://github.com/HubKing/LinkBrightness